# Storyboarddoesn't contain a view controller with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

Hello I did some research regarding this error but unfortunately the solutions provided did not work for me. I have a project where I first started working on redViewController. Then, on the same storyboard, I added a pageviewcontroller and on the swift file added redViewController as one of its views. I changed the entry point to be the pageViewController. When I run the application the error is still looking for the redViewController. I cleaned my code and this issue still happens, do I need to update anything else? I tried using instantiateViewController(withIdentifier) but it does not find my pageViewController. Thank you for your help!

Code:

AppDelegate-

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        //self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() //Looking for redviewController is it saved somewhere?
        self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController")
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure following field of the PageViewController is filled with identifier "PageViewController":

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, I tried this as well as deleting the app on the emulator, cleaning the app and re building. Do I have to change anything on my info list settings of the app or anything else?

Comment: Did you use another storyboard? not Main.storyboard?

Comment: I changed the name, but I also update my info file with the name, it works when i revert back to redViewController. All views are on the same storyboard

Comment: What storyboard file do you have now? Still named Main.storyboard?

Comment: yes I had changed it to test and it worked and changed it back to main, and update my info list as well and it works great but only when setting the redViwController as entry point

Comment: Actually I solved my issue it wasnt related to the storyboard, Since I had it the PageViewController the name it was obtaining for the views in the array was a character off, I updated it and it worked! Thank you again for your help!!